# Potractor not failing test even if it does not meet expected condition

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, chai, cucumberjs

I am new to protractor framework, even though the expected condition is not being met test is not failing

here is the output when i execute the test:

[image: TestOutput]

here is the code for the last step

```
this.Then(/^"View All Interactions" link button should stay at the top of list$/, () => {

    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink);
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getVisibleDataContainer());


    mobileQADashboard.getVisibleDataContainer().getLocation().then(function (ContainerLocation) {

        return expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink.getLocation(),"View Interactions Link is not above").to.eventually.have.property('y').that.is.below(
            ContainerLocation.y
        );
    })
});
```

1. why the step is passed even though the expect condition is not met
2. how to handle exceptions thrown by the expect conditions

Comment: I am not sure but try removing return before expect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using callback :

```
this.Then(/^"View All Interactions" link button should stay at the top of list$/, (callback) => {

    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink);
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getVisibleDataContainer());

    mobileQADashboard.getVisibleDataContainer().getLocation().then(function (ContainerLocation) {
        expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink.getLocation(),"View Interactions Link is not above").to.eventually.have.property('y').that.is.below(
            ContainerLocation.y
        ).and.notify(callback);
    })
});
```